# Ubuntu installation isn't working on Dell XPS 13 laptop running Windows 10

Tags: system-installation, dell, windows-10

I am following the instructions exactly as given by Ubuntu that says to make a bootable USB drive with Rufus using the ISO I downloaded from Ubuntu's website. However once I boot into it and start the installation, I never am given the option to "Erase Disk" which is what I want to do (I want to completely replace Windows with Ubuntu). And when I make it to the partition page, where it shows "+ - change..." Whenever I click one of those buttons the installation freezes or crashes completely. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Update UEFI, update SSD firmware, change drives from Intel RST to AHCI, turn off UEFI Secure boot and fast boot. If Windows still on disk, turn off Windows fast start up or Linux NTFS driver will not see it. https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln151664/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just needed to switch to AHCI mode and I was able to install cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to switch to AHCI mode in the BIOS of the laptop, so the installer could detect my SSD. Everything worked fine afterwards for me.

Comment: Found out the same when my Dell returned with a replaced battery, and my system would not boot ;-) The default is RAID, indeed.